# How to get only accepted answer in return from the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, answers, search, api

I found out that I could get only accepted questions from Stack Overflow using [this API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?page=1&order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&site=stackoverflow).

But now I want only the accepted answer to be part of the returned object; I don't need other answers. I know I can filter the returned array using the `is_accepted` tag to get the accepted answer. But is it possible to do it without it such that the API returns me only the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such filter in the method you're calling, [Advanced Search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search). Unless you're downloading thousands of questions, I don't think you should really worry about the bandwidth either.

I know of [one way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1) to search for accepted answers on the site itself, but it doesn't work as value for the `q` parameter, not even in the alternative [Excerpt Search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) operation.

An alternative *might* be to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) instead. It's a relatively simple SQL query requiring only a single join; if you're new to SEDE or SQL in general, please view the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).